# mongodb not showing default values of details in schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have created a schema as the one below.I have put the default values but when i check in mongodb atlas,it just shows that payment details is an array and does not show the details.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
paymentOption: [
    {
        card: [
            {
                cardNumber: {type: Number, default: 955},
                cardName: {type: String, default: 'aditya shrivastava'},
                CVV: {type: String, default: '888'},
            },
        ],
        upi: [
            {
                upiID: {type: String, default: 'aditya@oksbi'},
                bank: {type: String, default: 'sbi'},
            },
        ],
    },
],
});
const User = mongoose.model('UserSchema', userSchema, 'Updated-User-Data');
```

Comment: If you create the document in atlas directly it will not show the default values. You need to create a document using the node.js application you've made.

Comment: I have uploaded the code using nodejs by using insertMany in mongoose

Comment: Can you try it using model.save() function?

Comment: I am not saving those details as of now.So , I am just saving other details and expecting the default values for these.

Comment: Yes, but does using model.save() not inject the default values into the document?